# Why do packages disappear?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to run the talker program and the listener program.
After the talker program was executed, I opened new terminal and typed "rosrun beginner_tutorials listener" to implement the listener program which had made in CMakeLists.txt at the beginner_tutorials package .
Then the display said "No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials' ".
I'm sure I had ordered "source ~catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" before execution of the talker program, but I commanded it one more time, the program normally run.
Why did the beginner_tutorials package disappear? What was happened?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194703/why-do-packages-disappear?/) by [Shuta](https://answers.ros.org/users/20354/shuta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-10-10**:
Make sure the path your package resides in is listed in `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable (you can check by like `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Every new terminal that you open starts "clean", with only the minimal environment, plus any setup commands that you have in your `~/.bashrc`

Any `source` commands you run in one terminal do not affect other terminals.

If you want all of your terminals to start with your ROS environment set up, you should edit your `~/.bashrc` and add the appropriate setup command at the end.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1